# Multiprocessing: Can't pickle _thread.RLock objects

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-3.6, pickle, dill

In a Flask application, I have a function that is called in a for loop, I'd like to leave executing the process while continue executing the following processes until finishing the `for` loop.

This is the snippet of very basic scenario:

```
def get_most_similar_names(self):
    original_name = 'ABC ELEMENTARY EDUCATION'
    name_list = ['ABC ELEMENTARY SCHOOL', 'ABC KINDERGARDEN', 'ABC MIDDLE SCHOOL', 'ABC SOLUTIONS']
    vector1 = self.text_to_vector(original_name)
    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    return_dict = manager.dict()
    jobs = []
    for name in name_list:
        print('vector1: ', vector1, "type: ", type(vector1))
        print('name: ', name, " type: ", type(name))
        print("return_dict: ", return_dict, "type: ", type(return_dict))
        # For testing
        a = dill.pickles(vector1)
        b = dill.pickles(name)
        c = dill.pickles(return_dict)

        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.get_score, args=(vector1, name, return_dict))
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()

    for proc in jobs:
        proc.join()

    print(return_dict.values())


def get_score(self, vec1, n, return_d):
    vec2 = self.text_to_vector(n)
    print("in get_cosine function")
    intersection = set(vec1.keys()) & set(vec2.keys())
    numerator = sum([vec1[x] * vec2[x] for x in intersection])

    sum1 = sum([vec1[x] ** 2 for x in list(vec1.keys())])
    sum2 = sum([vec2[x] ** 2 for x in list(vec2.keys())])

    denominator = math.sqrt(sum1) * math.sqrt(sum2)

    if not denominator:
        cosine = 0.0
    else:
        cosine = float(numerator) / denominator

    return_d[n] = cosine

    print("return_dict:", return_d)

    return return_d
```

The purpose is to execute get_score function which receives vector1, name and a shared variable to store the results in a dictionary. However, when executing `start()` I am getting the following error:

```
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 105, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 223, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 322, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 65, in __init__
    reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 60, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
TypeError: can't pickle _thread.RLock objects
```

I assumed that the parameters are not pickleable, so I tested them, but they *are* pickleable. I've read that logger can produce this error, I found current_app.logger executions in other modules.

Do you know other factor can affect the execution of `start()`?

Comment: `multiprocessing.Manager`s use the built-in `pickle` module not `dill` to pickle objects being passed between processes. The latter can pickle more kinds of objects than the former — so you can't really claim `_thread.Rlocks` are pickleable (I wouldn't expect them to be). The good news is you may not need to them for `multiprocessing.Manager.dict`s.